# Fluid Simulation went wrong

Tags: animation

My Goal is a Box with closed doors hovering in the room with a golden Fluid flowing out of it.
My File was already looking good. 
I decided to change the Body of the inflow, but when I bake it the Result isn't looking right. [image]
The Fluid fidgets in a space but ignores my obstacle settings for the Sides.

Thanks for any help with getting my Fluid to flow properly in advance.

If you want to download the file here you go:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2KvkZumDeuJQmRfXzZBdlFPRnM

Answer (score 1):

Things have to be completely contained in the fluid domain in order to be considered/Calculated.  You may need to scale up the domain so it completely covers the scene and the obstacles.  Also, if your domain's scale is off, your particles may phase through things because of size differences.  Try scaling your scene up (to around 4 or 5 meters), but also know you will increase the cache size and simulation complexity.

I'll load this up later to make sure, but this looks a lot like my struggles with the fluid sim.